# IDW interpolation with noise values in ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, inverse-distance-weighted, multi-values, noise

I'm using ModelBuilder to create a noise map using IDW. But in the attribute table I have two columns with different values: Lden is the average of the values ​​throughout the day and Ln is the night values.
[image]

Do I have to create two IDWs from the shapefile?

So far, I have this in ModelBuilder and I think this doesn't work as planned.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you think your model does not work? Edit your question to provide more detail.